# Can I use only IP address connecting to a USB printer over a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: cups

Total noob here.  I have an iPad app that refuses to work with any printer that does not have ethernet or Wifi.  Is there a way to route the IP address of the Pi to the printer as if the printer itself was directly connected to the network?  Using CUPS and entering the path ip:631/printers/Printer_Name does not work.